# Microwave is now dimming and flickering lights and had been fine for over a year. Why?

Tags: electrical, lighting, microwave-oven

I understand the current draw issues of a Microwave.
My 1 Yr. Old Microwave had been running fine for the past year.
It is Plugged into a 20AMP circuit and the only thing on that circuit.
The Microwave and the Lights in the House had been fine no flickering and no dimming.
Recently as of Yesterday when the Microwave runs the LED Lights in the house will flicker / blink from time to time and some of them actually dim - depending on the brand of LED Light.

I do not notice my incandescent lamps doing anything unusual.
None of my other devices such as TV seem to be effected.

Why is this now happening ?
Is there any a real fact based cause that someone can provide for me and perhaps things to check or solutions.

Comment: The power line in filter on microwave is broken/defective. It supposed to filter out the frequency going back in the power line causing disturbance. The incandescent do not care about that, but LED lamps do care.

Comment: @Ruskes that sounds plausible - I did not think that the unit had the filter on the line being an appliance but thinking on it makes sense. I will look into the parts diagram online.

Comment: Are the LED lights new? What else has changed? You may have a lost neutral. Plug the microwave somewhere else in the house to see if the problem persists. Do the lights flicker when other appliances are running, like electrical stove, dryer, washing machine?

Comment: @P2000 Nothing has changed. All Led Lights have been in the house for at least 8-10 months others for longer. Except one set of designer LED lights - 4 months ago. 
If I lost the Neutral the GFCI would probably trip - entire Kitchen is on GFCI circuits except Fridge.

Comment: Use a multimeter to check voltage on each line to neutral, each line to ground and neutral to ground. Easiest is if you have a 240V/120V typical US clothes dryer on a 4-prong receptacle. If not, check several receptacles to (hopefully) get some on one hot line and some on the other. The concern is if you have a loose or broken connection on one wire at the street, at the meter or entering the main panel then you will get some strange results, and that can cause a *lot* of problems. If you have ~ 120V (anywhere 110V to 125V is OK as long as it is consistent and within a volt for the two hot

Comment: lines to neutral and to ground and basically 0V neutral to ground *and* no significant change (except perhaps a slight dip on *both* lines) when you turn on/off microwave or other major appliances then you can rule out this type of problem. But if you get something wacky...

Comment: Can you also please address other points in my comment? BTW, I'm not convinced the GFCI would trip. Any storms lately? Or nearby construction? Also, to isolate the lost neutral question, try other appliance (kettle) in same plug to see if problem repeats.

Comment: GFCI tests hot vs. neutral from that point forward. If you lost neutral coming into the house then the voltage for hot to neutral on a branch circuit would be wrong but the current would still be *balanced* and the GFCI would likely not trip.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact it is my understanding that open Neutral detection is built in to all modern circa 1995 and later GFCI's but I can not verify the details.

Comment: Open neutral means wire not connected from panel to this device. Lost neutral is from utility to main panel which is a different type of problem.

Answer (score 1):

As you can imagine the microwave generates high frequency interference operating at 2.5 GHz.

Mostly it sufficiently isolated to protect you from those frequencies but it is cooking anything in the microwave oven.

To prevent those EMI going out on the power cord there is a EMI filter in line.

Yours seems to be broken. When the EMI reaches the LED it will make it malfunction. LED lights depend on clean sinusoidal wave, which you do not have.

The incandescent lights do not care about EMI, they are just hot/glowing wire.

To test use a  power-bar with line filter.

The EMI filter is a small box (metal) where the power cable is connected to.

You will have to open the microwave to see it, and get the model/part number from it to buy replacement.

Comment: To confirm this, the OP can buy a plug-in line filter or power-bar with line filter, and try it out first.

Comment: @P2000 that would be the fix

Comment: yes, but I meant before buying a special part and opening the microwave. It's sometimes easier to return an item to an on-line giant or home improvement giant than deal with special orders.

Comment: @P2000 also that is good sugestion